# Unity - How to rotate sprite when it gets to the edge of the screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to rotate my sprite that moves right/left when it hits the edge of the screen (so it faces the direction it is moving in)

I got this so far:

```
function Start () {
    pos = Random.Range (-4.0, 10.0);
    transform.position.x = pos - 4.0;

    //transform.Rotate (Vector3.up * 180);
}

function Update () {
    pos -= Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position.x = Mathf.PingPong (pos, 10.0) - 6.0;    
}
```

how can I get this to work?

Comment: What is the error which you are getting?

Comment: im not getting an error, I get the sprite moving back and forth but it will only be facing one way. I want it to turn to the right when it hits the left edge, and other way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [transform.LookAt](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) and [Vector3.Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html):

```
transform.LookAt(Vector3.Slerp(Vector3.left,Vecto3.right, Mathf.PingPoing(pos, 10.0)));
```

Comment: this tells me Vector3 is undefined